# Prevent ASP.NET Web API Returning EntityKey

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, controller

In my Web API controller, I return the results to a method call like so:

```
// GET api/profile/5
public VCompleteProjectProfile GetBasicProjectProfile(int id)
{
    return _dbss.GetBasicProfile(id);
}
```

And here is the actual result:

```
{
    "$id":"1",
    "Id":1,
    "ProjectName":"Caribbean Challenge",
    "IsMrRcSelected":true,
    "IsMrdProject":true,
    "RegionName":"North America",
    "EntityKey":{
        "$id":"2",
        "EntitySetName":"VCompleteProjectProfile",
        "EntityContainerName":"MrdViewEntities",
        "EntityKeyValues":[
            {"Key":"Id","Type":"System.Int32","Value":"1"},
            {"Key":"ProjectName","Type":"System.String","Value":"Caribbean Challenge"},
            {"Key":"IsMrRcSelected","Type":"System.Boolean","Value":"True"}
        ]
    }
}
```

Is it possible to suppress the `EntityKey`? If so, how? This is MVC4.

Thanks
Eric

Comment: Create a DTO with the information you wish to return. Populate the DTO with the information it requires from your database. Return the DTO from your controller.

Comment: If you use POCOs instead of old entity object based entities there will be no `EntityKey` at all - only Id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a DTO/POCO for your result instead of returning the actual entity object e.g.

```
var entity = _dbss.GetBasicProfile(id);
return new ProfileDto()
{
    Id = entity.Id,
    ProjectName = entity.ProjectName,
    ....
};
```

You could even extend your entity type to include a function called `ToDto` which would do this for you e.g.

```
public partial class ProfileEntity
{
    public ProfileDto ToDto()
    {
        return new ProfileDto()
        {
            Id = this.Id,
            ProjectName = this.ProjectName,
            ....
        };
    }
}

....

var entity = _dbss.GetBasicProfile(id);
return entity.ToDto();
```

A general rule of thumb is only return data that is *needed*, don't cut corners just because it's convenient.

Also, if you find yourself having to do this all over the place look at something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/), will make your life a lot easier.